# Is there an OData Server Library for Java or PHP to EXPOSE OData?

Tags: odata

I am wondering if there is or why there isn't a ADO.NET Data Services Server Library for Java?

I need to expose a database from a Java Server but i only see Microsot providing clients for java not server parts.

How is that an open standard when you need .NET/Windows to expose it?

Thanks for any pointers to that. Same interesting for PHP as well.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what does OData do for you that Atom Publishing Protocol doesn't?

Answer (score 7):

Check out odata4j - pure java odata implementation - both client and server side.

http://www.odata4j.org

Answer (score 2):

Now there is one available for PHP: OData Producer Library for PHP

http://odataphpproducer.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1):

There is also an Apr 6, 2010 sourceforge.net project, [od4j](http://od4j.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

SAP just releaseed their OData sdk on github, you can check here:
https://github.com/SAP/cloud-odata-java

Apache have one incubating project for OData, you can check here:
http://olingo.incubator.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

Apache [Olingo](http://olingo.apache.org/) will be the first to support OData 4.