# Odata rest services with apache httpd server

Tags: apache, odata, rest-client

I want to integrate odata services in to apache httpd web server so that I can     get data using rest client like "postman" in chrome. Is there any kind of implementation is there? please guid me.

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail?  For example, you could describe the type of data you want to expose and how it is currently stored.  For example, is it in a relational database like MySQL?

Comment: I want to get data from one process and covert into odata format and give response to rest client ,So I can get data from process by IPC.So what I'm looking for that I have apache httpd module which can accept rest api from rest client and give that data to my process by IPC and convert data to odata format and give back to rest client in json format

Comment: It sounds like you will need to write an application to convert the native data representation of the source process into OData directly.  Hosting such an application in apache is secondary.  Have you looked at the libraries listed on www.odata.org?  You may want to make your question even more specific, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470283/is-there-an-odata-server-library-for-java-or-php-to-expose-odata for an example